# How do you debug your Nest queries?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to Nest, and I very likely am not creating my query like I think I am.  My question is more along the lines of teach a man to fish rather than give me a fish.  However, I'll use my current problem as an example.

I have several documents in ElasticSearch of the type `Series`.  I'll stub it out below without the attributes and public modifiers with just the information pertinent to the query:

```
class Series
{
    string Id {get; set;}
    DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
    DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
    HashSet<Role> ReleasableTo {get; set;}
}
```

These are all fine and dandy.  I can `Get()` a `Series` object no problem.  The problem I'm running into is trying to figure out how Nest is formatting my query.  My immediate goal is to find the most recent `Series` that is releasable to `Role.Visitor`.  I set up the Nest query like this:

```
ISearchResponse<Series> response = client
    .Search<Series>(r => 
         r.Filter(f => 
             f.Term<Role>(t=>t.ReleasableTo.First(), Role.Visitor))
    .SortDescending(ser => ser.EndDate).Size(1));
```

In my mind, this should be producing a query that filters the Series so it only considers the ones that are `ReleasableTo` my `Role.Visitor`, reverse sorts by end date, and limits the results to one returned.  That would be exactly what I want.  In the multiple thousands of records I have for Series, about 90% fit this profile.  Unfortunately the query returns 0 results.  There is no error, just no results.  What I don't know is if I'm using the API incorrectly, if Nest is producing a query structure that doesn't make sense, or I simply don't know ElasticSearch well enough.  When I remove the `Filter` clause I get a result, but I'm not guaranteed everyone is allowed to see it.

How do I view the JSON that Nest produces and sends to ElasticSearch?

Comment: For future readers, take a look at the documentation on logging and debugging: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html

Comment: if you have typeORM integration you can try to set `logging: true` in your orm configuration ([docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the values of search request URL and JSON request body as under:

```
var requestURL = response.RequestInformation.RequestUrl;
var jsonBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestInformation.Request);
```

You can find other useful properties in `RequestInformation` for debugging.

Comment: That's very helpful, for what it's worth, if I do a "query": {"match":{"releasableTo": "Visitor"))  I get what I want.  I think my index needs some fine tuning.

Answer (score 9):

`NEST` is Baroque of .NET APIs. For 2.1+ on call level:

```
IElasticClient client = new ElasticClient();
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<Series>();
var query = Query<Series>.Term(...);
var pretty = query.ToPrettyString(query);
var json = client.ToRawRequest(searchDescriptor.Query(descriptor => query));
```

On configuration level:

```
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings()
                     .PrettyJson().DisableDirectStreaming()
                     .OnRequestCompleted(details=> Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.RequestBodyInBytes)));
```

On response level look into `CallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes`.

Used extensions:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts search to raw JSON request for debugging.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="self">The self.</param>
    /// <param name="searchDescriptor">The search descriptor.</param>
    /// <returns>The string.</returns>
    public static string ToRawRequest<T>(this IElasticClient self, SearchDescriptor<T> searchDescriptor) where T : class
    {
        using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            self.Serializer.Serialize(searchDescriptor, output);
            output.Position = 0;
            var rawQuery = new StreamReader(output).ReadToEnd();
            return rawQuery;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints query into string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The self.</param>
    /// <returns>The value.</returns>
    public static string ToPrettyString(this QueryContainer self)
    {
        using (var settings = new ConnectionSettings())
        {
            var visitor = new DslPrettyPrintVisitor(settings);
            self.Accept(visitor);
            return visitor.PrettyPrint.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
        }                                                                         
    }
```

Comment: PrettyJson, DisableDirectStreaming, and OnRequestCompleted can all be done in one call with `EnableDebugMode` in newer versions of nest. See my answer below for example.

Answer (score 7):

I like to take it a step further than bsarkar suggests and eliminate the need for a roundtrip altogether:

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var seriesSearch = new SearchDescriptor<Series>();
seriesSearch.Filter(f => f
    .Term<Role>(t => t.ReleasableTo.First(), Role.Visitor))
    .SortDescending(ser => ser.EndDate)
    .Size(1));

string searchJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.Serializer.Serialize(seriesSearch));
```

Note that your ElasticClient doesn't need any connection properties, so you have no dependency on an ES node.

Comment: Note, in NEST 2.4.5 the Serialize function no longer returns a string and must take a target Stream as a parameter. e.g.

            using (var searchRequestStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                client.Serializer.Serialize(seriesSearch, searchRequestStream);
                var searchRequestString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchRequestStream.GetBuffer());
            }

Answer (score 6):

Really easily. If this is my code that searches:

```
var results = client.Search<SearchItem>(s => s.AllIndices()
    .Query(q =>
            q.Term(p => p.LastName, searchItem.LastName)
            && q.Term(p => p.FirstName, searchItem.FirstName)
            && q.Term(p => p.ApplicationCode, searchItem.ApplicationCode)
            )
    .Size(1000)
    );
var list = results.Documents.ToList();
```

I then set a breakpoint on the line above.
Then, in Visual Studio Immediate Window, I enter this:

```
?results.ConnectionStatus
```

and it gives me this:

```
{StatusCode: 200, 
    Method: POST, 
    Url: http://localhost:9200/_all/searchitem/_search, 
    Request: {
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "lastName": {
              "value": "carr"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "firstName": {
              "value": "adrian"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a really useful technique.

Comment: Not sure what I am missing, but I see no ConnectionStatus property on my results object

Answer (score 4):

Using the latest elastic search 5+, I was able to get mine (thanks to Adrian Carr's method) with the following:

```
var jsonOutput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
    response.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes
)
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
      ...
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested in **Nest 6.2.0**

The call `EnableDebugMode` will automatically call `DisableDirectStreaming`, `PrettyJson`, and then `OnRequestCompleted`, passing in the lambda you give it.

So, now you can just do something like:

```
connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode(details =>
{
  Logger.Debug($"ES Request: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.RequestBodyInBytes ?? new byte[0])}");
  Logger.Verbose($"ES Response: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.ResponseBodyInBytes ?? new byte[0])}");
});
```

NOTE: The responses seemed to be lacking closing brackets for me. It would seem there may be a bug somewhere in the nest response stuff. Doesn't seem to affect anything but the logging.

Answer (score 2):

**Elasticsearch.Net and NEST: the .NET clients [7.x]**

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html`

1. Enable DisableDirectStreaming in ES Global setting like following.

ref code

```
Var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .DisableDirectStreaming(true); 

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

2.)  `var response = client.Search<Project>(s =>....)`

3.)

```
var jsonOutput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
            result.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
```

Above can be achieved on a per request basis with following.

```
var response = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .RequestConfiguration(r => r
        .DisableDirectStreaming() 
    )
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EnableTrace` or `ConnectionStatusHandler`. More details [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/864).

Answer (score 0):

In my current version of Elasticsearch.NET/NEST (7.13.2), I can catch the `ElasticsearchClientException` and take advantage of the [`DebugInformation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html). If `DisableDirectStreaming` is set like in the other answers then the full request body is included.

```cs
try {
    // do some elastic stuff
} catch (ElasticsearchClientException e) {
    Logger.LogInformation(e.DebugInformation);
    // handle error
}
```