# How to only return a subset of properties with ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Say I got an ElasticSearch up and running with and Blog object.

```
 public class Blog
 {
     [ElasticProperty(Name = "guid", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
     public Guid? Guid { get; set; }

     [ElasticProperty(Name = "title", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";

     [ElasticProperty(Name = "body", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
     public string Body { get; set; } = "";

     [ElasticProperty(Name = "publishedDate", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.Date)]
     public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would only like to return a subset of the properties into a new class

```
 public class BlogListItem
 {
       public static Expression<Func<Blog, object>> Selector = e => new BlogListItem
        {
            Title =  e.Title,
            PublishedDate = e.PublishedDate,
        };

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Normally I work with Entity Framework where I would write an Selector like in the BlogListItem class, but I'm finding it hard to find any information about doing this in ElasticSearch with NEST

```
var res = elastic.Search<Blog>(s => s
           .From(0)
           .Size(3)
           .Index(blogIndex)
           .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
           .Sort(o => o.OnField(p => p.PublishedDate))
           .Fields(BlogListItem.Selector)
           );

  var result = res.Hits.Select(e => e.Source).ToList();
```

This returns the correct number of Hits, but with an null source and I can't figure out where to find the returned properties.

**Solution 1**
I found an alternative solution, but would like input if this is a good solution.

```
var res2 = elastic.Search<Blog, BlogListItem>(s => s
             .From(0)
             .Size(3)
             .Index(blogIndex)
             .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
             .Sort(o => o.OnField(p => p.PublishedDate))
             );

List<BlogListItem> resultList = res2.Hits.Select(hit => hit.Source).ToList();
```

This gives me the correct object returned, but I don't have any control about mapping, and I'm not sure if it returns all properties and then do the mapping.

**Solution 2.5**
In this solution i have updated my BlogListItem with a new Selector.

```
    public class BlogListItem
    {
        public static SearchSourceDescriptor<Blog> Selector(SearchSourceDescriptor<Blog> sr)
        {
            return sr.Include(fi => fi.Add(f => f.Title));
        }

        [ElasticProperty(Name = "title")]        
        public string TitleNewName { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And then my elasticSearch code

```
var res3 = elastic.Search<Blog, BlogListItem>(s => s
                .From(0)
                .Size(3)
                .Index(blogIndex)
                .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
                .Sort(o => o.OnField(p => p.PublishedDate))                   
                .Source(BlogListItem.Selector)
                );

            List<BlogListItem> resultList = res3.Hits.Select(hit => hit.Source).ToList();
```

Now this limits the properties returned so I only get Title and the PublishedDate is null and I know have control on the mapping thanks to

> [ElasticProperty(Name = "title")]

Still needs to verify if this is the correct way of working with ElasticSearch.

This produces the following Json

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3,
  "sort": [
    {
      "publishedDate": {}
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "title"      
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

Using `.Fields(BlogListItem.Selector)` returns a field called "publishedDate.title" which of course is wrong. I'm not sure how to use the `Expression` syntax for mentioning fields so I'll not try to fix it. I found this bug by printing the request JSON. Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28140778/1797393) to another question on SO to know how to debug Nest queries by printing the request JSON. May be you can fix the `Expression` syntax yourself using this trick :)

I fixed `Fields()` using the syntax I'm best familiar with:

```
.Fields(f => f
    .Add(t => t.Title)
    .Add(t => t.PublishedDate)
```

Even with this fix, you'll find that source is `null`. We come to the next problem. If you provide `"fields"` option in the search request, `"_source"` will not be present in the response hits. This is Elasticsearch's behaviour and has nothing to do with Nest. In this case, you have to rely on `Fields.FieldValuesDictionary` instead of `Source`:

```
var result = res.Hits.Select(e => e.Fields.FieldValuesDictionary).ToList();
```

Then you can build `BlogListItem` objects from the result above.

Comment: do you know anything about the Source propertie? It just seemds like alot of work to get the properties back from a FieldValuesDictionay

Comment: I think you've done a good job with source filtering. That is the best solution (solution 2.5) I guess.