# Searching in multiple elasticsearch indexes using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am trying to search for a text in elasticsearch using nest 7.10.1. I want to search in two different indexes, I get a response in the form of documents, but I cannot access its properties because the result has the combination of two indexes. Below is the code I tried. Both the indexes has same properties. What do I use in the foreach loop to access the key and values of the result documents.

```
public void searchIndices(string query) {
    var response = client.Search<object>(
      s => s.Index("knowledgearticles_index, index2")
            .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field("locationName")
                         .Query(query))));

    Console.WriteLine(response.Documents);
    
    foreach(object r in response.Documents) {
      
    }
}
```

I am using elasticsearch 7.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two indices that you're searching over contain different JSON structures, then the `T` in `Search<T>` will need to be a type that the differing JSON structures can be deserialize to. `object` will work as per the example in your question, but then there is no typed access for any of the properties.

A simple approach to overcoming this is to [hook up the `JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) and then use `JObject` for `T`

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings =
    new ConnectionSettings(pool, sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default);
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

var response = client.Search<JObject>(s => s
    .Index("knowledgearticles_index, index2")
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("locationName")
            .Query(query)
        )
     )
);
```

We now have a way of accessing properties on `JObject`, but will still need to handle the type of each property.

Comment: @KomalKartan If it helped, please upvote. And if it solved the question, please mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Each raw hit coming back in [the search response](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-response-body) has the [`_index` meta field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html) associated with it:

```
"hits" : {
  "total" : {
    "value" : 91,
    "relation" : "eq"
  },
  "hits" : [
    {
      "_index" : "knowledgearticles_index",   <---
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "r_oLl3cBZOT6A8Qby8Qd",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        ...
      }
    }
```

Now, in NEST,

> `.Documents` is a convenient shorthand for retrieving the `_source` for each hit

-- meaning that you'll have lost access to the meta properties.

So the trick is to [use a loop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#_matching_documents) like this instead:

```
foreach (var hit in response.HitsMetadata.Hits) {
  Console.WriteLine(hit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, how do I access the values of each property. For example i want to retrieve all the documents from 2 indexes with a particular text. How to I retrieve them and print them on the console.

Comment: I am able to get response with 10 hits. My question is how do I access the values inside them and print them?

Comment: Updated my answer at the bottom. Hope it helps.

Comment: my console looks like this now.
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]
Nest.Hit`1[System.Object]

Comment: I'm not too familiar w/ NEST to help you further... Printing objects to the console is out of scope if this question but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28140778/8160318) may help.